# Understanding headers and include

Tags: c, include, header-files, pragma, include-guards

I am trying to grasp how actually multiple definitions of include files collaborate and sometimes collide. So I have a custom header file `file.h`, where some functions are declared within an `#include guard`. Example:

```
#ifndef FILE_Ariew7OGJknw00
#define FILE_Ariew7OGJknw00

#include <stdlib.h>  //assume minimal

//interfaces of functions

#endif
```

Now I have several questions.

**1.** Since `#include <stdlib.h>` is already included in the header `file.h`, I don't need to include it in my `file.c`. Because `file.c` includes the `file.h` which includes `stdlib.h`. However when I include `<stdlib.h>` after `file.h` in my `.c`, it still works properly. Why is that so? Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
//code
```

**2.** Also what happens if I do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file.h" 
//code
```

In reality *nothing* but why isn't `file.h` definition skipped (*or is it?*) based on the guards, since the library `stdlib` is *already* included.

Lastly, a more general question: Why are #include guards more widespread used than `#pragma once` even though the latter has several advantages such as:

> • less code 
> • avoidance of name clashes (i.e. `FILE_Ariew7OGJknw00`)
> • improvement in compilation speed

Comment: A header is not a library. And C does not declare a library, but functions & variables and define types.

Comment: @Olaf Yes. I editted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However when I include  after file.h in my .c, it still
>   works properly. Why is that so?

Because the standard headers have include guards too. So when include it multiple either directly in your code or through another source file, it's skipped.

> why isn't file.h definition skipped (or is it?) based on the guards,
>   since the lib is already declared.

An include guard doesn't do any check whether any headers or included or not. It doesn't care/know what's inside.

The preprocessor simply checks if the include guard macro `FILE_Ariew7OGJknw00` is defined or not. If defined, it's skipped. Otherwise, it's *pasted* into your soruce file where you included it.

> Why are #include guards more widespread used than #pragma once even
>   though the latter has several advantages

It's non-standard. So it makes your your code less portable.

---

It's not recommended to include other header files in a header file needlessly. You won't see multiple inclusion issues in practice as it'll work as expected due to include guards. There may be legitimate cases where you need to include other headers. For example, if you have a header like:

```
/* header.h */

#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

#include<stdio.h>

struct my_struct {
   size_t len;
   char *s;
};

void my func(void);
void my_blah(int);

#endif
```

Then it becomes necessary to include `<stdio.h>` to get `size_t` definition. If you don't then the souce file that includes this header will have to include `<stdio.h>`. But a header should be to work on its own without forcing the user of it to know all the dependencies.

As a convention, a header file should only have the declarations and other header inclusions in it should be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

1.
The language standard requires that the standard headers can be included several times without a problem. It doesn't say exactly *how* that works, but include guards is of course one way.

3.
 One problem with `#pragma once` is that it is non-standard. The standards committee does not want to define exactly how it is supposed to work on all possible file systems, for all possible operating systems. If you have several network mounts from unknown sources and some hard-linked files, it can be very hard to determine which files are the same.

On Windows and Linux it works with all major compilers. On other systems, we don't know.